# How to do linear regression on categorical independent variable in excel?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear, large-data, functional-data-analysis

I am newbie in data analytics world and I am trying to do linear regression on super-store sales database.
The database contain fields like OrderID, OrderDate, ShipDate, ShipMode, CustomerID, CustomerName, Segment, Country, City, State, PostalCode, Region    , ProductID, Category, Sub-Category, ProductName, Sales, Quantity, Discount, Profit

Question:
1) I am trying to do linear regression on state and sales field, because want to know which state is important in terms of sales. I have tried to do that in excel, and got something like below. So how to interpret this?
[image]

[image]
2) Can you suggest me the better way to do figure out the fields for linear regression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the IVs and DVs of your model?

Comment: Why the `functional-data-analysis` tag?

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt: Independent variables are order date, city, state, productId
While dependent variables are sales, profit.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not a simple linear regression. Your IVs have a categorical variable and a time series and you have bivariate DV. In your case, I would stick to simple linear regression. So use only one DV. Not sure why productID would be informative, maybe remove it. If you want city and state, consider a planned contrasts methodology. I'm your case, I think including the date might be too much right now

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt Thank you for your response. So, here Discount -> Profit or Discount -> sales will be good example in terms of linear regression. RIght?

Comment: Are you saying a categorical variable representing profit or discount moderates the relationship between discount and sales, or mediates the relationship? What you typed is like a path model, not really a regression equation. I'm not trying to be critical, I just want to help you, but I need to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt Thanks again! Actually I am learning this things. I want to know, if we can do linear regression then which fields we can use?

Comment: Simple linear regression has one continuous IV and one continuous DV.